# Application failed codesign verification

Tags: xcode, app-store, codesign

I know that there are many articles all over the Internet about this, but no matter how hard I try, I can't find an answer to this question:

I want to submit my finished app to the iOS App Store. I just archived my iOS application in Xcode 4, and I clicked the "Validate..." button in the Organiser. When the app is validated, Xcode tells me this:

```
Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was
not signed with an Apple submission certificate.
```

I have a distribution profile that I used to codesign in the target app.

I am not using Application Loader because it is telling me that

```
Application Loader is currently unavailable... an error occurred talking to the
iTunes store
```

But the question is, what is wrong with my app, and how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check 2 things in the build log (detail view), search for "embedded.mobileprovision" to see if it's embedded, and check under "CodeSign" if the certificate is the one that you are using for distribution.